# CSS border-right in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the following code and for some reason in last version of chrome the border-right doesn't dissapear, only if you highlight the column on the right. just copy the code and you will see. thank you.

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Highlighting</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
#decor-table {
  font-family: Calibri, "Times New Roman", Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#decor-table th {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: rgba(153,153,153,1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#decor-table td {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  color: #369;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#oce-first {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.2);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.5);
}
.hover_class {
  color: rgba(225,225,225,1) !important;
  background: rgba(204,204,204,0.2);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.5);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.5);

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  var cellClassName = false;
  $("td, th").hover
  (
      function()
      {
          cellClassName = $(this).attr("class");
          $("." + cellClassName).addClass("hover_class");
      },
      function()
      {
          $("." + cellClassName).removeClass("hover_class");
      }
  );
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="900px" id="decor-table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="oce-first">
      <th width="17%" class="col1">test</th>
      <th width="18%" class="col2">test</th>
      <th width="13%" class="col3">test</th>
      <th width="11%" class="col4">test</th>
      <th class="col5">test</th>
      <th width="16%" class="col6">test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2">test</td>
      <td class="col3">test</td>
      <td class="col4">test</td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2">test</td>
      <td class="col3">test</td>
      <td class="col4">test</td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2">test</td>
      <td class="col3">test</td>
      <td class="col4">test</td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2">test</td>
      <td class="col3">test</td>
      <td class="col4">test</td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2">test</td>
      <td class="col3">test</td>
      <td class="col4">test</td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6">test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2">test</td>
      <td class="col3"></td>
      <td class="col4"></td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">test</td>
      <td class="col2"></td>
      <td class="col3"></td>
      <td class="col4"></td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1"></td>
      <td class="col2"></td>
      <td class="col3"></td>
      <td class="col4"></td>
      <td class="col5">test</td>
      <td class="col6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't make people copy/paste code. http://jsfiddle.net/Auqcz/

Comment: You're giving table width:900px and you're giving each individual th in %. Try to give them also in px

Comment: Fix your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` .. no that doesn't make it work but you don't want IE to trigger quirks mode ..

Answer (score 3):

Well known `Chrome artifacts`

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iluqif/4/edit)**</kbd>

```
.hover_class {
  color: rgba(225,225,225,1) !important;  
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.2);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.5);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,0.5);

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);    /* THIS WILL FIX IT */
}
```

Using `%` (table cells are by default in `%`) Chrome plays to be smart and uses some sort of `half-pixel-precision`, that leads the pixels to travel to the next one leaving trails known as "artifacts" so you'll need some sort of hackish "repainting".

If you use strict PX math positioning you'll also get rid of the 'issue' 

Additionally you can use `box-shadow` to get 98% rid of this unfriendly lines.

if I were you, I would use transparent borders on the initial state, so no jumps will be visible

Comment: I tried your solution with '-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);' and on my offline solution looks the same, even if on [Yours Solution](http://jsbin.com/iluqif/4/edit) looks good.

Then, I tried to add transparent borders on the initial state, and for some reason I can't see border-left anymore. The code can be viewed [Here](http://jsbin.com/iluqif/9/edit). Thank you.

About 'box-shadow', I am not really sure how to use that.

Comment: @grenntrancer sure they're not showing up, cause you use `border-collapse;` :)

Comment: well, if I remove that, it will look really ugly, so that's the hole point .... :) and i don't really know for what problem you are talking about `border-collapse`...

Answer (score 0):

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r4Res/2/embedded/result/)**

I think the problem is with your `table width` as you've provided them with `px` value and given th in % so I have changed completely to % as shown

```
<tr id="oce-first">
  <th width="20%" class="col1">test</th>
  <th width="20%" class="col2">test</th>
  <th width="20%" class="col3">test</th>
  <th width="14%" class="col4">test</th>
  <th width="16%" class="col5">test</th>
  <th width="10%" class="col6">test</th>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm still seeing persistent borders every now and then with your demo

Comment: @Phil-Updated with new demo